# Esta função tem um tipo de retorno de 'Widget', mas não termina com uma instrução de retorno

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  DataBaseHelper db = DataBaseHelper();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Map<String, dynamic> args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    Session session = args['session'];
    void selecao(escolha) async {
      if (escolha == 'logout') {
        session.autenticado = 0;
        await db.updateSession(session.userId, session);
        Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, '/');
      }
    }

    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _onBackPressed,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Home'),
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          actions: [
            PopupMenuButton(
              onSelected: selecao,
              itemBuilder: (context) {
                return [
                  PopupMenuItem(
                    child: Text('Sair'),
                    value: 'logout',
                  )
                ];
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              textColor: Colors.black,
              color: Colors.yellow,
              child: Text('Contatos'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home/contatos');
              },
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              textColor: Colors.black,
              color: Colors.yellow,
              child: Text('Mapas'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home/mapa');
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<bool> _onBackPressed() {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Deseja sair?'),
            actions: [
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('Sim'),
                onPressed: () {
                  SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop');
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('Não'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              )
            ],
          );
        }
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Como posso resolver? Segue o código (acho que dar pra entender).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o próprio erro deixa explícito o que está errado. E ele deve inclusive estar indicando qual a linha com problema, mas você não colocou o stacktrace na pergunta..

Então baseado no código fornecido, o problema deve estar no builder do `showDialog`, você não está retornando nada nele.

Repare [na assinatura](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetBuilder.html) do `Typedef` do builder que ele recebe:

`Widget WidgetBuilder (BuildContext context)`

É obrigatório retornar um `Widget`.

```dart
Future<bool> _onBackPressed() {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog...
        }
      );
  }
```

Adicione o `return` no `AlertDialog`.